# Form how to get div element from span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having form for uploading picture, which contains many divs. I want to get the name of that picture which is inside div containing span.

```
<form class="dropzone dz-clickable dz-started" action="form_upload.html">
<div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-error dz-complete dz-image-preview">
<div class="dz-image">
//skipped as it is showing complete image 
</div>
<div class="dz-details">
   <div class="dz-size">
      80kb
   </div>
   <div class="dz-filename">
     <span data-dz-name="">aust_ews.PNG</span>
   </div>
 </div>

</div>

</form>
```

I'm trying to get the **aust_ews.PNG** but failed to get.

Here is my tries:

```
var e =$(".dz-filename").val();//failed

var e =$("#form dz-filename").val();//failed
```

Comment: user3162878: please try to use real words here, even in comments. This is not a chatroom - please make all of your material as readable as possible. Surely "but", "not", "please" etc are not too much effort to type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.val()` fetches the value (think of input fields), but you need the contents between the tags - you need `.html()`.
Apart from that, you need to fetch the contents of the inner `span`, not the outer `div` - otherwise, the result would be `<span data-dz-name="">aust_ews.PNG</span>`.

In code:

```
var e = $('.dz-filename span').html();
```

If it still doesn't work, verify that you have the jQuery library loaded.
You can check in the console by simply typing in `$` and pressing enter. It should state something like "function".

It's good practice to execute things like that inside `ready`. Just to be sure it'll work in the way you're expecting:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var e = $('.dz-filename span').html();
});
```

About `ready` see more on [jquery.com manual](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: bt when i do alert it does nt print anything for checking.

var e = $('.dz-filename span').html();
alert(e);

Comment: Must be an error on your page. [It works in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfh77a14/). Do you have jQuery loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$(".dz-filename").val();
```

try

```
$(".dz-filename").text();
```

As what ever html or text present inside the div is not the value, it is the content of that div. And you can get it by using html() or text().

`val()` works only with input elements like text, select, radio, checkbox as it searches for the `value` attribute and return it.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0gxwd09/)

Comment: bt when i do
 var e =$(".dz-filename").html();

alert(e);

does nt print anything

Comment: Check the working fiddle link in the answer: https://jsfiddle.net/t0gxwd09/

Comment: i did bt page gives jquery error:
ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Jquery library is not included in your page, include it and try again

Answer (score 1):

Please check this. It's working here. I have checked with the alert.

You just need to pass your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){}`function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var e = $(".dz-size").html();
alert(e)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="dropzone dz-clickable dz-started" action="form_upload.html">
<div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-error dz-complete dz-image-preview">
<div class="dz-image">
//skipped as it is showing complete image 
</div>
<div class="dz-details">
   <div class="dz-size">
      80kb
   </div>
   <div class="dz-filename">
     <span data-dz-name="">aust_ews.PNG</span>
   </div>
 </div>

</div>

</form>
```